# Is there a way to recover ubuntu 14.04 to a previous configuration?

Tags: 14.04

I am a newbie in Ubuntu and I know that in windows we are able to recover the system to a previous configuration. Some days ago I was trying to install a python package and I think I did a lot of modifications in the system. Now, I am not able anymore to install Spider (python idle that was working well before that).

1) So, is there a way to recover ubuntu 14.04 to a previous configuration?

2) Are my document files affected by this procedure?

Ubuntu is the only system in my computer. I do not have anything else.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extensive log in `/var/log/apt/` which keeps track of what exactly you have been installing and/or updating, complete with the actual commands (if commands were used). See what is in there: uninstall packages that seem to cause trouble and reinstall lower-numbered versions.